# Is the pseudo code written below correct for the question (write a pseudocode to find out if the given number is a prime number)?

Tags: pseudocode

Is the pseudo code written below correct for the question

```
Input a number

X = number - 1
If X mod 2 = 0 then
    Print number, “is not a prime number”
Else
    Print number, “is a prime number”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are just lowering the entered number by one and check if it is divisible by 2.

Basically, you would have to do something like this:

- take a variable (let's say **x**) and set it to 2
- while the **input mod x** is not zero and x is smaller than half of input do:
- add one to x
- if there was never input mod x = zero then input is a prime

Beware that this is not optimized at all, but the concept is correct.